# How to create custom WooCommerce 2.0 templates

Tags: plugins

I'm working on a site for a client who is using version 2.0.1 of WooCommerce plugin and I'm lost as to how I can create new page templates for it.

With previous versions of the plugin is was simple, you just copied files from the "templates" folder into your theme folder and boom! But now, that folder is gone.

The WooThemes documentation is still being updated to reflect the upgrade to 2.0 so that's no help.

Any assistance would be more appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you need to buy some sort of premium support ticket over there. From looking through the [tag:woocommerce] archive over here, it seems that we haven't got any real experts (or even half ones) and Woo seems to say "Fuck you" (read Adiis blog) to non-paying customers.

Comment: You may want to trace the code of the 3 free official WooCommerce themes. http://www.woothemes.com/product-category/themes/woocommerce/?prod_cat%5B%5D=100&s=&post_type=product

Comment: This page has some good pointers: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the templates folder is [still included](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/tree/master/templates) in WooCommerce, just like before. Just copy its contents to yourtheme/woocommerce and, hey presto, it works!

N.B. This doesn't work when you use the [woocommerce_content()](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/#usingwoocommercecontent) function in a woocommerce.php.

WooThemes actually have a [good primer page](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/) that they even link from a nag after you have installed WC2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Does the install have the Woocommerce default pages included on the WP backend?

If your client skipped adding these when they installed Woocommerce it may have also not grabbed the templates.
You could try re-installing Woocommerce and making sure you select the option to add the default pages when it comes up then check if you have the page templates.